# Change z index of objects programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing this application where the z there are two buttons above each other. when clicking one of them the other should be visible and clickable.

I first thought about changing the z index by setting:

self.buttonOne.layer.zPosition=50;
self.buttonTwo.layer.zPosition=100;

So their they would flip and then the other button would be viewable and clickable.

What actually happened is that it became viewable but not clickable. When I press the button nothing happens.

I tried this method in different forms, I tried it on table views and cells and this was the same behavior.

How can I change the z index in a appropriate way?

Comment: You can use `bringSubviewToFront` and `sendSubviewToBack` on the containing view.

Comment: can you set .hidden=YES for one button, and .hidden=NO for another?

Comment: Thank you That solved my problem (using hidden). And that worked with the tableviews too. But is this an appropriate way for doing such functionality ? Or its better to put every control in a view and then use bringSubviewToFront and sendSubviewToBack ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative way is to disable the button that will be going to the back and setting its alpha value to 0, and setting the other to enabled with an alpha value of 1.

Comment: Thank you That solved my problem (using hidden). And that worked with the tableviews too. But is this an appropriate way for doing such functionality ? Or its better to put every control in a view and then use bringSubviewToFront and sendSubviewToBack ?

Comment: @MostafaMohamedRaafat it's really just multiple ways of solving the same problem. It's not to say that one is better than the other, as neither of them impact performance very much.